# Prestashop smart cache for css mess up site

Tags: css, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I enable smart cache for css, prestashop frontend will be messed up totally, like only using some of the css.

However, I can see there is all my custom css rules, also blocks and modules in that same file, but I can't understand why it messes it up so bad. Basically its just html dumped together with float effects when I enable it.

It it better to look for other css compiler/minifier and not to use prestashop one? is this general issue ?

Site works perfectly fine after I disable it again...
Using prestashop 1.6.1.6
Any idea how to debug ?

Comment: Have you installed a template?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general issue, this must be happening because of the custom theme that you are using on your store.

You can try removing the theme specific cache from the following directory:

/themes/YOUR_THEME/cache/

You may refer to the following link as well if you have upgraded from 1.6.1.4 to 1.6.1.5 recently.

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/520452-update-from-1614-to-1615/page-2

Comment: I removed cache and it made new .css which it is using but still no luck :( all my css stuff is in that file tho but when making it to one file, it messes up the order or so because all my rules are in that file but they are not working. if they are without the css smart cache it will work just fine.